# ExtrudeGeometry issue for SVG Containing Hole

Tags: svg, three.js

I am currently looking for extruding the SVG below:

[image]

But I get the following result:

[image]

I would extrude only the two hexagon wall space. How can I do it ?

I tried both SVGLoader.createShapes(path); and //path.toShapes(true);

Here is my code:

```
const loader = new SVGLoader();
    // load a SVG resource
    loader.load(
        // resource URL
        './svg/hexagone.svg',
        // called when the resource is loaded
        function (data) {

            const paths = data.paths;
            const svgGroup = new THREE.Group();
            svgGroup.name = "svgGroup"
            svgGroup.scale.y *= -1;
            let mesh;

            for (let i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
                const path = paths[i];
                
                const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
                const shapes = SVGLoader.createShapes(path); //path.toShapes(true);

                shapes.forEach((shape, i) => {
                    const geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, {
                        depth: 10,
                        bevelEnabled: false
                    });
                    geometry.computeVertexNormals();
                    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                    svgGroup.add(mesh);
                });
            }

            // Reshape items
            const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(svgGroup);
            const size = new THREE.Vector3();
            box.getSize(size);

            const zOffset = size.z / -2;
            const yOffset = size.y / -2;
            const xOffset = size.x / -2;

            svgGroup.children.forEach(item => {
                item.position.z = zOffset;
                item.position.x = xOffset;
                item.position.y = yOffset;
            });

            scene.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(5))
            scene.add(svgGroup)

            // Rotate           
            svgGroup.rotateX(90 * Math.PI / 180);

        }
```

My add my SVG below. When I tried to debug, I get 4 meshes. 1 for each line, 1 for the outside hexagon (overlapping the inside hexagon), 1 for the inside hexagon.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 53.86 53.86">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: #fff;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <polygon class="cls-1" points="15.98 53.36 .5 37.88 .5 15.98 15.98 .5 37.88 .5 53.36 15.98 53.36 37.88 37.88 53.36 15.98 53.36"/>
    <path d="M37.67,1l15.19,15.19v21.48l-15.19,15.19H16.19L1,37.67V16.19L16.19,1h21.48m.41-1H15.77L0,15.77v22.31l15.77,15.77h22.31l15.77-15.77V15.77L38.08,0h0Z"/>
  </g>
  <g>
    <polygon class="cls-1" points="20.63 44.31 10.96 34.64 10.96 20.96 20.63 11.29 34.31 11.29 43.98 20.96 43.98 34.64 34.31 44.31 20.63 44.31"/>
    <path d="M34.1,11.79l9.38,9.38v13.26l-9.38,9.38h-13.26l-9.38-9.38v-13.26l9.38-9.38h13.26m.41-1h-14.09l-9.96,9.96v14.09l9.96,9.96h14.09l9.96-9.96v-14.09l-9.96-9.96h0Z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

With another SVG (see below) the result is the same even if in this scenario I have 2 paths in the SVG.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Fusion 360, Shaper Origin Export Add-In, Version 1.6.10  -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:shaper="http://www.shapertools.com/namespaces/shaper" shaper:fusionaddin="version:1.6.10" width="3.1176915cm" height="3.6cm" version="1.1" x="0cm" y="0cm" viewBox="0 0 3.1176915 3.6" enable-background="new 0 0 3.1176915 3.6" xml:space="preserve">
<path d="M-0,-1.8 L1.5588457,-0.9 1.5588457,0.9 -0,1.8 -1.5588457,0.9 -1.5588457,-0.9 -0,-1.8z" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,1.5588457,1.8)" fill="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
<path d="M-0.9588457,0.5535898 L-0.9588457,-0.5535898 -0,-1.1071797 0.9588457,-0.5535898 0.9588457,0.5535898 0,1.1071797 -0.9588457,0.5535898z" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,1.5588457,1.8)" fill="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="0.0010cm" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
</svg>
```

Hexagon inside is also recovered by the biggest.

[image]

Comment: Maybe your svg has issues like wrong subpath path directions or uses clip-paths or masks to cut out the inner shape. Please add the hexagon's svg markup to your question.

Comment: Is the hexagon made using one or two paths?

Comment: SVG added in the post.  I hope it would help to identify what going wrong with my SVG.

Answer (score 0):

I finally chose to use lnkscape to generate my SVG. I have mush more options and I was able to generate the hole by combining all pathes in 1 path.